# Karma Html Reporter reload test when I try to navigate through the HTML document

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to use *Karma* and *Jasmine* to test my Angular 7.2 application.
It works fine, except one thing : when I click on a test name, it's refreshing the page and re executing all the tests again. The same happen when there is a failure and I click to "Spec List". I though a click on the test name should redo only the clicked test(s) and "Spec List" click should only go to the list of Spec showing which are passing and which don't.

Any idea why ?

**karma.conf.js** :

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
        plugins: [
            require('karma-jasmine'),
            require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
            require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
            require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
            require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
            require('karma-mocha-reporter')
        ],
        client: {
            clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
        },
        coverageIstanbulReporter: {
            dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage/gts-ui-extensions-rc'),
            reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
            fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
        },
        reporters: ['mocha', 'kjhtml'],
        port: 4300,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        singleRun: false,
        restartOnFileChange: true
    });
};
```

**dev dependencies :**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.12",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.3.12",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^11.13.0",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.0.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.5",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "^8.0.3",
    "tslint": "^5.15.0",
    "typescript": "3.1.1",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6"
  }
```

Comment: I'm having this issue also. I know virtually nothing about testing angular apps. As a _horrible_ workaround - if you remove the `href="#"` from the spec-list anchor tag (in Chrome debugger for example) - then clicking the link will show the list... _Please_ let me know if you find out what the real problem is though!

Comment: Same here.  I was able to repro the problem with a 'blank' angular app out of the box.  Just have to cause one test to fail to get the 'Spec List'.

Comment: Added a bug to the karma-jasmine-html-reporter, as this appears to be a bug with that component:  https://github.com/dfederm/karma-jasmine-html-reporter/issues/26

Comment: Facing same issue. Any solution ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue even with updating to the latest package.

Comment: This is not a valid answer but I managed to work around it for now by clicking the DEBUG button in the top bar (added this same comment on the main github issue).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some script is redirecting the `<a href='#'> </a>` links to the home page, while by default nothing should happen.

This problem is being addressed here: [jasmine issues 1775](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1775)

See the changes made to this pull request: [pull request 1807](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/pull/1807/files)

A temporary solution would be to apply the [pull request 1807](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/pull/1807/files) changes to this file: **node_modules\karma-jasmine-html-reporter\src\lib\html.jasmine.reporter.js**